# Limits of functions of two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am not very familiar with the limiting behviour when two variables go to infinity. In particular, what I need to show show is the following:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{r \to \infty} [r \exp(-\beta n)]=0,$$ where $\beta>0$. Is this true? What is a rigorous way to show it?

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: Because you evaluate the inside limit first,

$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}r\exp(-\beta n)$

which already doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}$ (it's divergent).

Comment: What if he wrote $n = \alpha\cdot r$ for some good $\alpha$?

Comment: What a good $\alpha$ can be?

Comment: $\alpha > 0$ for example, and finite. I don't see anything wrong in performing that change.. Even if actually I don't know if it's the right procedure.

Comment: Both r and n are integers by the way

Comment: If that steps held, then you'd have

$$\lim_{r\to + \infty} re^{-\alpha\beta r} = 0$$

Comment: That's what I thought, but applying the first limit first makes the function goes to infinity for a fixed n, which I am not sure if this the way that we should proceed with this limit

Answer (score 0):

Well to me it's just a question to perform a change of variables, setting

$$n = \alpha\cdot r$$

so that one has

$$\lim_{r\to +\infty} r e^{-\alpha\beta r} = 0$$

Considering that

- $\alpha > 0$
- $\beta > 0$
- Both $n$ and $r$ are integers

**Actually it seems this is not a correct answer...**

Comment: But you don't get to decide how $n$ and $r$ tend to infinity. If the limit exists, it should be the same regardless of which paths $n$ and $r$ follow to infinity. What if $r = \exp(\beta n)$?

Comment: Mm right.. there are lots of possible paths, and that one would make the limit to be $1$ So you're saying it doesn't exist because it should be independent from the chosen path?

Comment: Yeah - exactly.